# .designer file of migration in EF core not being associated with .cs file in visual studio

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have created a .NET Core application. I am using Entity Framework Core with Code first approach and I am creating migrations.

For some reason the `.designer.cs` file of the migration is not associated with the principal `.cs` file.

[image]

I have seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145171/designer-file-not-being-associated-with-cs-file-in-visual-studio) but it seems is not correct for .net core application.

Any help please?

Thank you

Comment: mine are separate too, but no issues running it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Update** instead of **Include**.

In your `.csproj` file, add these lines to the `ItemGroup`:

```xml
<Compile Update="yourfilename.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>yourfilename.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: If you use Microsoft Identity Core it generate a first migration called `CreateIdentitySchema` that has the `Deisgner` as sub od the `.cs`... But If I generate it with add-migration something goes wrong... however everything works correctly... it was just a personal "obsession"