# Visual Studio how bad is it to add code in the designer files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I often read other people's code and once in a while, I saw some code added in a Designer file.
when I try to understand why some developers write code in a designer file, I often find myself arguing for hours with them.
Is there a Microsoft rule not to do it or is it open for anybody ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manual editing of \*.designer.cs file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161994/manual-editing-of-designer-cs-file)

Comment: I would counter argue with why would you put code in a designer file? Not sure of a solid reason for it TBH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment in the designer file should say enough:

> This code is generated. Modifications will be lost when this code is regenerated.

Therefore, there is a risk: you can lose your modifications and / or additions.

Do note, some generators use `#region` markup to mark what they will generate. For example LLBLgen. However usually these files are not named with `.designer.cs`.

As for the discussion, a few arguments:

- usually designer generated files are `partial`. So the class can be edited in the other file. If something in the designer file needs changes, best is to use the generator tool instead.
- Code quality tools like Stylecop and code metrics usually are configured to ignore designer generated files. You might miss important feedback.

Comment: Other good answers are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161994/manual-editing-of-designer-cs-file

Comment: @FredSmith Indeed thats why I marked it as a duplicate a few minutes ago! :)